# Confused with global variables in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. In the code below, I have declared three variables `TGt_x`, `TGt_y`, and `TGt_z`. When I try to use these variables in my `compute` function, I am getting an `Undefined reference error`. Why is this happening?

```
import sys
import math
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot,pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
Range = 2000.0
Brg = 330.0
Crs = 120.0
Elevation = 50.0
V = 40.0

TGt_x = Range * math.cos(Elevation) * math.sin(Brg)
TGt_y = Range * math.cos(Elevation) * math.cos(Brg)
TGt_z = Range * math.sin(Elevation)

Vx = V * math.sin(Crs)
Vy = V * math.cos(Crs)
Vz = 0.0


def compute():
    TGt_z = TGt_z + Vz
    TGt_x = TGt_x + Vx
    TGt_y = TGt_y + Vy
    print("TGTx=============================",TGt_x)
    print("TGTy=============================", TGt_y)
    print("TGTz=============================",TGt_z)
    Range = math.sqrt(pow(TGt_x, 2) + pow(TGt_y, 2) + pow(TGt_z, 2))
    print("Range=============================",Range,"\n")

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(compute)
timer.setInterval(1000)
timer.start()
sys.exit(app.exec_())*
```

Comment: Which line does the error message say your Undefined reference happens at?

Comment: TGt_z = TGt_z + Vz,
 TGt_x = TGt_x + Vx, TGt_y = TGt_y + Vy,All these three lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you don't use global variables like this. Change your code to:

```
def compute():
   global TGt_z,TGt_x,TGt_y
   //your code
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `global` statement inside the `compute` function:

```
def compute():
    global TGt_z, TGt_x, TGt_y #here
    TGt_z = TGt_z + Vz
    TGt_x = TGt_x + Vx
    TGt_y = TGt_y + Vy
    print("TGTx=============================",TGt_x)
    print("TGTy=============================", TGt_y)
    print("TGTz=============================",TGt_z)
    Range = math.sqrt(pow(TGt_x, 2) + pow(TGt_y, 2) + pow(TGt_z, 2))
    print("Range=============================",Range,"\n")
```

---

Small example:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> def compute():
...     x+=5
... 
>>> compute()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in compute
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
>>> def compute():
...     global x
...     x+=5
... 
>>> compute()
>>> x
10
>>>
```